# Pandas pivot_table with Category and Object datatypes yield different results

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, categorical-data

Consider the following data frame:

```
data = {'person_id': [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,6], 
        'admission_id': [123,234,234,234,345,456,567,678], 
        'timespan': ['12h', '12h', '24h', '36h', '12h', '12h', '24h', '48h'], 
        'label': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'], 
        'value': [56,170,170,170,65,64,53,150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The datatypes of each column are as follows:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 5 columns):
admission_id    8 non-null int64
label           8 non-null object
person_id       8 non-null int64
timespan        8 non-null object
value           8 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3), object(2)
memory usage: 400.0+ bytes`

The table before transformation is as follows:

[before_pivoting_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmYl.png)

Performing a pivot_table transformation yields the following table:

```
df.pivot_table(values='value', index=['person_id', 'admission_id', 'timespan'], columns='label', fill_value=0)
```

[object_datatype_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRe2N.png)

My ideal table structure is one where each row of person_id and admission_id shows values for all 4 values of timespan ie 12h, 24h, 36h and 48h, even if it is all null values.

I then tried to convert 'timespan' into a categorical datatype as such:

```
df['timespan'] = df['timespan'].astype('category')
```

Performing yet another pivot table yields a completely different result:

[category_datatype_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB2K6.png)

I get the display of all 4 possible values of timespan now on each row, but my 2nd level row index, admissions_id, becomes categorised as well. Each admission_id now appears with each person_id.

To clarify, each admission_id is unique to each person_id, that is there will be no duplicate admission_ids but a person_id can have more than one admission_id.

Is there any way to create my ideal table structure which should look something like this?:

```
person_id admission_id timespan A  B   C
     1        123         12h   56 0   0
                          24h   0  0   0
                          36h   0  0   0
                          48h   0  0   0
     2        234         12h   0  170 0
                          24h   0  170 0
                          36h   0  170 0
                          48h   0  0   0
     3        345         12h   0  0   65
                          24h   0  0   0
                          36h   0  0   0
                          48h   0  0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(values='value', 
                     index=['person_id', 'admission_id', 'timespan'], 
                     columns='label', 
                     fill_value=0)
df2 = df1.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

Or very similar:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(values='value', 
                     index=['person_id', 'admission_id'], 
                     columns=['label', 'timespan'], 
                     fill_value=0).stack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['person_id', 'admission_id', 'timespan', 'label'])['value']
         .mean()
         .unstack(level=['label','timespan'])
         .fillna(0)
         .stack()
         .fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df2)
```

---

```
print (df2)
label                             A    B   C
person_id admission_id timespan             
1         123          12h       56    0   0
                       24h        0    0   0
                       36h        0    0   0
                       48h        0    0   0
2         234          12h        0  170   0
                       24h        0  170   0
                       36h        0  170   0
                       48h        0    0   0
3         345          12h        0    0  65
                       24h        0    0   0
                       36h        0    0   0
                       48h        0    0   0
4         456          12h        0    0  64
                       24h        0    0   0
                       36h        0    0   0
                       48h        0    0   0
          567          12h        0    0   0
                       24h        0    0  53
                       36h        0    0   0
                       48h        0    0   0
6         678          12h        0    0   0
                       24h        0    0   0
                       36h        0    0   0
                       48h        0  150   0
```

Comment: Which dataframe did you perform your unstacking and stacking on? I tried it on the original data frame and got the following error:

    'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: I add it to answer now, please check it.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first approach and it works. I think it's important to note that the data frame must not have any 'category' datatypes prior to performing the pivot_table transformation, otherwise the result will be very different.